# Borel regular measure: Approximate any measureable set by compact sets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(K,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ be a regular finite measure. We said that it is *regular* if

$\mu(A) = \inf\{\mu(B): B \text{ open }, A\subset B\}$ and $\mu(U) = \sup(\mu(K) : K \text{ compact }, K \subset U\}$ for any measurable $A$ and any open $U$.

Given a measurable set $A$ and $\epsilon >0$. My Professor states that one can find a compact set $B\subset A$ such that $\mu(A\setminus B)< \epsilon$.

I don't quite see it as $A$ is not open. Is this true?

Comment: I don't think this is the right statement. Can you read it over and edit it?

Comment: If the measure is $\sigma$-finite, then the claim holds true.

Comment: Thanks, $\mu$ is finite, forgot to awrite.

Comment: @saz How can I prove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A \in \mathcal{F}$ be a measurable set. Fix $\epsilon>0$. By assumption, there exists an open set $B$ such that $K \backslash A \subseteq B$ and

$$\mu(B) \leq \mu(K \backslash A) + \epsilon. \tag{1}$$

The set $\tilde{K} := K \backslash B = B^c \subseteq A$ is compact and satisfies

$$\begin{align*} A \backslash \tilde{K} = A \backslash B^c &= A \cap B = B \backslash A^c = B \backslash (K \backslash A). \end{align*}$$

Looks like that:

$\hspace{120pt}$ [image]

Consequently,

$$\mu(A \backslash \tilde{K}) = \mu(B \backslash (K \backslash A)) = \mu(B) - \mu(K \backslash A) \stackrel{(1)}{\leq \epsilon}.$$

Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, this finishes the proof.

Comment: Oh, pretty picture. Thanks!